# Returns a object from RouterFunction handlers in Spring 5 WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflow, project-reactor

I have the following bean definition for a RouterFunction:

```
@Bean
    RouterFunction<?> routes(DestinationHandler destinationHandler) {

        return nest(path("/destination"), route(method(GET), destinationHandler::findAll));

    }
```

And this the handler function:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> findAll(ServerRequest request) {
    Flux<Destination> destinations = destinationService.findAll();

    ResponseData responseData = buildResponseData(destinations);

    return ok().body(Mono.just(responseData), ResponseData.class);

}

private ResponseData buildResponseData(Flux<Destination> destinations) {
    ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
    responseData.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    responseData.setCode(DESTINATION_LIST_SUCCESS_CODE);
    responseData.setMessage(DESTINATION_LIST_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
    responseData.setData(destinations);
    return responseData;
}
```

And my ResponseData:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResponseData {
    private int status;
    private String code;
    private String message;
    private Object data;
}
```

Destination class:

```
//lombok annotations
public class Destination {
    private int id;
    private String local;
}
```

This result in this:

{
   "status":200,
   "code":"destination_list_success",
   "message":"Retorno realizado com sucesso",
   "data":{
      "scanAvailable":true,
      "prefetch":-1
   }
}

How can I return the correct destination list?

Comment: What is wrong with the result? You are assigning the `Flux` to the `Data` field, that is also what you are seeing in your JSON response.

Comment: I updated the question with destination class definition.

Comment: That doesn't matter... You are assigning the `Flux`. The `Flux` is lazy and you have to pull to get the content. Just creating JSON out of it isn't going to pull all the results from the Flux.

Comment: Hmmm.. ok. I "solved" with this:

responseData.setData(destinations.toStream().collect(Collectors.toList()) ... 

This is the best way?

Comment: You basically now reduced your non-blocking solution to a blocking solution. Loosing the benefit of using project reactor.

Comment: But how can I resolve in the non-blocking way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you need transform `Flux<Destination>` into a `Mono<List<Destination>>`, so make the following changes:

```
buildResponseData(Flux<Destination> destinations)
```

to:

```
buildResponseData(List<Destination> destinations)
```

and change return block to this:

```
return ok().body(destinations.collectList().map(d-> buildResponseData(d)), ResponseData.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private ResponseData buildResponseData(Flux<Destination> destinations) 
{
    ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
    responseData.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    responseData.setCode(DESTINATION_LIST_SUCCESS_CODE);
    responseData.setMessage(DESTINATION_LIST_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
    responseData.setData(destinations.block());
    return responseData;
}
```

and also change ResponseData class to be

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResponseData {
    private int status;
    private String code;
    private String message;
    private List<...> data;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but still returns:

{"scanAvailable":true}

Answer (score 0):

You should flip the order. Following Carlos' answer:

```
return destinations.collectList().map(d-> ok().body(buildResponseData(d)));
```